# How to composite and compress Javascripts (.net ajax) to get best performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I use JQuery library and some customised JavaScripts in my web app. I combined and compress them into one JavaScript file and located it at the **end of body** as static script, which normally can get the best performance, agree?

```
<script src="../js/Default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Moreover, there are some .net ajax controls e.g.`<ajax:calendarExtender>` applied in some pages. Some articles, http://am-blog.no-ip.org/BlogEngine/post/2010/04/12/Increase-AJAX-Performance-by-combining-Scripts-using-Scriptmanager-Composite-Scripts.aspx suggest using `<asp:CompositeScript>` to composite default asp.net JavaScripts which are required by those controls e.g.`<ajax:calendarExtender>`

Since my web app only have one **ScriptManager** which is located in the MasterPage at the **beginning of the Form**. What is the best way to composite and compress those .net JS to make the use similar as my static script? Since those ajax controls are not applied in every page, should I still composite all JavasSripts in Master Page? (guess reference-proxy in each child page wont help?)

Regards,

Comment: Edit: well, I'd like to use CompositeScript to reduce the number of http request. If I list all the .net javascripts which are used in some of the pages in CompositeScript in a MasterPage. Will it reduce the performance for these pages that doesn't using .net JSs?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not need to compress more this files, other than gZip.

Of course you need here to be sour that your js files on webresource are not the debug versions.

If you try to change the location of this files, eg try to place them on the end, then maybe you get javascript errors because this functions are probably needed to be found by asp.net controls

I only suggest to add **some cache on the client side**. You can do that on Application Begin Request - something like:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the file name
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    // here just see if this is the files that you wish to add some extra cache
    if (cTheFile.EndsWith("WebResource.axd", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // add some cache - what ever you think, or add an eTag 
        app.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4));
        app.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0));
        app.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, but not quite understand. 'js files on webresource are not the debug versions.' , how? by list all of them in CompositeScript?

Comment: Second, I think cache has been set in webConfig, any benefits to set it in application_beginrequest ?

Comment: @Dan An you speak about net js files, the javacript files that automatically net add to your site, this files are both debug and release versions. I say to place it on beginRequest because I do not know where else you can place this cache - if you know please tell me so.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscation will shrink the size of a script (sometimes dramatically).  IMO that is **all** that obfuscation is good for.